# vim copy into clipboard with colon cmd

Tags: vim, raspberry-pi, vi

I want to yank multiple lines with a colon command into the UNIX-clipboard without visual mode, like this:
`:1,4"+y`
or
`:1,$"+y`

The clipboard is active --> `echo has('clipboard')` returns `1`

I'm on raspberry pi and tried gvim and vim.
Can anybody shed some light onto this?
Thank you and kind regards!

Comment: OMG, they joy is back - made my day!  

@bk2204 - awesome!
@Enlico - `:11,13y | let @+ = @"` also works great

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible with the `:yank` command, which can be abbreviated `:y`.  It takes as its argument the register without the `"`.  So, your examples could be written as so:

```
:1,4y +
:1,5y +
```

While it's possible to do this with the `:normal` command to do this with something like `:normal 1G4"+yy`, this would be a lot more complex and needlessly so.  `:yank` is simpler and more flexible if you're fine with linewise operations.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer is amazing! I didn't know of the `:y` ex command.

Just for completeness, an alternative a bit more verbose is that you can yank in the default register `"` (i.e. as you would do normally in Vim-only workflow) and then just copy the content into the other register via `:let @+ = @"`.